# How to insert multiple instances of an image into html using FileReader.readAsDataURL()?

Tags: javascript, html, image, filereader

I want to insert an image that a user selects from their local machine using `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` into multiple `<img>` elements on a single html page.

Using the example code provided by the [MDN docs for `FileReader.readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL), **the image only gets inserted into the first `img` element, not the rest**.

I thought the reason the image is only inserted into the first `<img>` instance is because the example code uses `document.querySelector('img')`. However, when I use `document.querySelectorAll('img')`, it still does not work.

The MDN docs provide [a working codepen example](https://codepen.io/bzelip/pen/dOQdwG) that you can see in action. Here is their static code:

```
<!--html-->
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

and

```
//js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Here is [a working codepen of my code](http://codepen.io/bzelip/pen/vyQqZJ), and below is my static code.

```
<div>
  <label>Select an Image</label>
  <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
</div>

<div>
  <img id="small" src="http://placehold.it/900x900"/>
  <img id="med" src="http://placehold.it/1200x1200"/>
  <img id="large" src="http://placehold.it/1500x1500"/>
</div>

<script>
  function previewFile() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('img');
    var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      preview.src = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Can anyone offer some help to get the user selected image to populate all of the `<img>` elements on the page instead of just the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure to correctly understand your need.
If it's like this:

- you expect *only one* file (image) to be selected through your `<input>`
- and you want this unique image to be the same source of *all* your `<img>`s

Then below is the way to go:

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    for (var img in preview) {
      preview[img].src = reader.result;
    }
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Select an Image</label>
  <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
</div>

<div>
  <img id="small" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  <img id="med" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img id="large" src="http://placehold.it/300x300"/>
</div>
```

The main points are:

- `preview` gets *all* `<img>`s (as you already tried)
- then we use a `for()` loop to process *each of them* (here was your lack)

Comment: Hi @cFreed, both of your assumptions are correct. However, when I replace your javascript with mine, I don't get the image to load at all. See this codepen which allows you to toggle between the two code blocks using comments -- http://codepen.io/bzelip/pen/mOQZYK

Comment: @BrianZ Sorry, there was a bug: I wrote it quickly and didn't test! The error was to create as many `FileReader` objects as `<img>`s, while there is only one file. Look at my updated answer: now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The code will need to iterate over all the files in the file list and then assign each (via Object-URL) to separate image element.

I would suggest the following changes as there is really no need for `FileReader` at this point. The `URL.createObjectURL()` can be used with `File` blobs as well and save us from some headache:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=file]").onchange = previewFile;

function previewFile() {

  var files = this.files;                               // "this" = input element
  var parent = document.querySelector(".imageList");    // parent element
  var i = 0, file;
  
  while(file = files[i++]) {                            // iterate over file list
    var img = new Image();                              // create new image instance
    img.src = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(file); // use File blob directly
    parent.appendChild(img);                            // insert image in DOM
  };
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Select an Image 
  <input type="file" multiple>             <!-- make sure multiple is enabled -->
  </label>
</div>

<div class="imageList"></div>
```

If you want to *replace* an image list simply obtain the list of images using `querySelectorAll()` instead of `querySelector()`, then replace the sources from the list until one run dry:

```
//... as before
var img, images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

while((file = files[i]) && (img = images[i++])) {       // loop until one runs dry
    img.src = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(file); // use File blob directly
};
```

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=file]").onchange = previewFile;

function previewFile() {

  var files = this.files;                               // "this" = input element
  var parent = document.querySelector(".imageList");    // parent element
  var i = 0, file;
  var img, images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

  while((file = files[i]) && (img = images[i++])) {     // loop until one runs dry
    img.src = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(file); // use File blob directly
  };
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Select an Image 
  <input type="file" multiple>             <!-- make sure multiple is enabled -->
  </label>
</div>

<div class="imageList">
  <img id="small" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  <img id="med" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img id="large" src="http://placehold.it/300x300"/>
</div>
```